# How to let player jump on any surface?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've followed a brackeys tutorial for the FPS Character Controller, but If I replace the ground, which is a cube, with terrain or any other thing, the character wont jump. Here is my PlayerMovement Code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the ground layer on the terrain?

Comment: What do you mean? I can't jump on any object other than my ground for some reason

Comment: Well with the code you gave us the obvious answer is your terrain was not marked in layer ground...

Answer (score 0):

Actually to fix it all you need to do is set the ground mask on your first person player to everything and you should be good to go! Thanks to BugFinder for trying to help.

Comment: except that now makes your character get affected by gravity less, wierd?

Comment: Now just set the ground distance to 0.2 and you should be good to go!

Comment: well by srtting it to everything everything will count as ground which may not be the case.....